# Adding a Second Text Area to a Flask App

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app. I tried to add a second text area to the app to add another function. I copied the text area exactly and I receive the following message when I his submit on the lower box:

Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Here is the code all that was changed from the original app is adding a second text area identical to the first. It appears ok but the problem arrises when I hit submit even if the text area name is changed. I don't understand how the server sees a difference between the 2nd and first box at this point. Heres [the app that's being changed.](http://ven-diagram.herokuapp.com/) Its about as sophisticated as you would expect given this question. Thx!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ven Diagram</title>
<style type=”text/css”>
#pagearea {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
textarea {
width: 48%;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
input {
width: 80px;
height: 40px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagearea">
    <h1>
    This program allows you to match text. The text must be unicode.
    Enter two text blocks to compare:
    </h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <textarea name="A" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
      <textarea name="B" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Execute" />
    </form>
    </div>

 <div id="pagearea">
    <h1>
    This will give add and subtract permutations for numbers. 
    </h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <textarea name="A" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Execute" />
    </form>
    </div>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            Results:
            <pre>
                {% for message in messages %}
{{ message }}
                {% endfor %}
            </pre>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Python code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import flask, flask.views
import os
import urllib

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "REDACTED"

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('index.html')

    def post(self):
        A = flask.request.form['A']
        B = flask.request.form['B']
        A = urllib.unquote(unicode(A))
        B = urllib.unquote(unicode(B))
        C = A.split()
        D = B.split()
        Both = []
        for x in C:
            if x in D:
                Both.append(x)
        for x in range(len(Both)):
            Both[x]=str(Both[x])
        Final = []
        for x in set(Both):
            Final.append(x)
        MissingA = []
        for x in C:
            if x not in Final and x not in MissingA:
                MissingA.append(x)
        for x in range(len(MissingA)):
            MissingA[x]=str(MissingA[x])
        MissingB = []
        for x in D:
            if x not in Final and x not in MissingB:
                MissingB.append(x)
        for x in range(len(MissingB)):
            MissingB[x]=str(MissingB[x])
        #flask.flash("A:")
        #flask.flash(A)
        #flask.flash("B:")
        #flask.flash(B)
        #flask.flash("C:")
        #flask.flash(C)
        #flask.flash("D:")
        #flask.flash(D)
        flask.flash("Words in Both:")
        flask.flash(Final)
        flask.flash("Words in First Box Only:")
        flask.flash(MissingA)
        flask.flash("Words in Second Box Only:")
        flask.flash(MissingB)
        return self.get()

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])

app.debug = True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to include your Python code as well, especially since it looks like the problem is originating from the server.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the third box? You are getting an error because the second submit button submits the third textarea only with a name of `A` to the same post method, which expects both A and B.

Answer (score 1):

even if you might think it's overkill. I learned that I want to use flask extensions in every possible way there is.

In your case i would recommend [wtforms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with [flask-wtf](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to better handle any sort of forms.